# Set AUTO_INCREMENT value in sqlite3 using knex.js

Tags: auto-increment, reset, knex.js, node-sqlite3

I'm using the `knex v0.19.1` with `Node.js`. I've searched through entire [Docs](http://knexjs.org/) of `knex.js` but didn't find a way to reset `AUTO_INCREMENT` to specific value knex way. Is there any workaround to achieve this? or i need to execute the pure query as `alter table TAB_NAME set AUTO_INCREMENT = 45` by `sqlite3` driver itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use raw query to do that, but you can do it for example with `knex.schema.raw()`. No need to use sqlite3 driver directly.

Comment: actually, I'm looking for the way to utilize every unique id, no auto-incremented id should be left unused if someone deletes data. You are correct for a `row` query. have you any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your comment correctly, but I got an impressiona that you would like to reuse ids of deleted rows. Normally one does not start filling ids that are left unused when rows are deleted. If you really want to do it you should not use AUTO_INCREMENTING ids.

Comment: You understood correct, `AUTO_INCREMENT` will not help in this case. Thanks for suggestion.